# What does "1" mean at the end of a php print_r statement?

Tags: php

My `print_r($view)` function yields:

```
View Object
(
    [viewArray:View:private] => Array
        (
            [title] => Projet JDelage
        )
)
1 <--------------
```

What does the "1" at the end mean? The PHP manual isn't very clear on how to parse the output of `print_r`.

Comment: it should not show, check your script once? some other part is display it or in html you have that.

Comment: When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the return value is TRUE. http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You probably have `echo print_r($view)`. Remove the `echo` construct. And... what need do you have to parse its output? There are certainly much better ways to solve your problem.

Comment: or set return to true `print_r($view, true)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: Bingo, thank you.  I meant parse as in understand, or read, for me, as a human being.  Sorry - it was ambiguous...

Comment: Best answer to exactly what I was looking for -_- thanks lonut

Comment: Searched for 10 minutes!

Answer (score 21):

print_r called with one argument (or with its second argument set to false), will echo the representation of its parameter to stdout. If it does this, [it returns TRUE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). Thus if you `echo print_r($foo)` you will print the contents of foo, followed by a string representation of the return value (which is 1).

Answer (score 2):

When using print_r to return, than than output/print the value, pass the 2nd parameter which defines `return` as true.

```
echo print_r($view, true);
```

This is useful if you want to save the results to a variable or concatenate with another string.

```
$var = 'The array is: ' . print_r($view, true);
```