# A character 1 after every value I get from the database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I try to get some values out of my mySQL database using CodeIgniter. But when I do so the values I print out on the screen show up with a character `1` behind it.
Any way to solve this issue or an explanation why this might happen?

My Product_model.php code:
https://i.gyazo.com/7320302979a2687648a6f5ae3ed3dece.png

```
class Product_model extends CI_Model
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->load->database();
  }

  public function getProducts($id = FALSE)
  {
    if($id === FALSE)
    {
      $query = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('products')
                    ->join('productimages', 'productimages.productID = products.ID')
                    ->where(array('productimages.thumbnail' => 1))
                    ->group_by("products.ID")
                    ->get();
      return $query->result_array();
    }
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name, description, products.price, products.added_by, products.date_added FROM `products`");

    return $query->row_array();
  }
}
```

My output:
https://gyazo.com/5d35e8f266fecb3cddfa3b550feb0a0a

Notice that there is a `1` after every time I print out a value.

I hope somebody knows a fix.

Kind regards,
Potato

Comment: Please post code as text not a picture of the code

Comment: Where are you outputting? Are you using `print_r`? My guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771039/what-does-1-mean-at-the-end-of-a-php-print-r-statement.

Comment: @chris85 How could I have not thought about that... Just one of those little things you dont look for. Thanks mate!